# Problemas con un JMenu

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica, jmenubar

Buen día, estoy realizando un ventana que contiene en la parte superior una barras de menu el cual tiene varios menús (datos , proceso, editar, opciones, ventana y ayuda ) como se  muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que la parte donde están las opciones de grabar área de trabajo, Recuperar área de trabajo y cambiar estado se sale de la venta principal me gustaría hacer que esa parte se colocara hacia la izquierda como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo el código donde realizo el armado :

```
   public void armado() {
        ventana.add(panel);
        panel.add(barra, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        barra.add(Dato);
        barra.add(Proceso);
        barra.add(Editar);
        barra.add(Opcion);
        barra.add(Vent);
        Vent.add(cascada);
        Vent.add(mosaico);
        Vent.add(anterior);
        anterior.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, Event.CTRL_MASK));
        Vent.add(posterior);
        posterior.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_P, Event.CTRL_MASK));
        Vent.add(op_prin);
        op_prin.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F10,0));
        Vent.addSeparator();
        Vent.add(area_tab);
        area_tab.add(grabar);
        area_tab.add(rec);
        area_tab.add(est);
        barra.add(Ayuda);  
    }
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes recurrir a sobreescribir el método `getPopupMenuOrigin()` del `JMenu` para que devuelva una nueva ubicación del componente emergente, en algun lugar de tu código:

```
area_tab=new JMenu("Area de Trabajo") {
  @Override
  protected Point getPopupMenuOrigin() {
    if(getContentPane().getWidth()<605)
      return new Point(-this.getPopupMenu().getPreferredSize().width,0);
    else
      return new Point(Vent.getPopupMenu().getPreferredSize().width,0);
  }
};
```

Allí `getWidth()` representa el ancho del `JFrame` y la medida `605` puede que no sea la mas exacta para algunos *LAFs* por aquello que no todos renderizan gráficos y fuentes del mismo tamaño, es solo cuestión de ajustar.

Comment: que tal hice lo que me indicaste pero solo lo coloca al lado izquierdo si agrando la ventana no lo coloca de lado derecho el tamaño de mi JFrame es (600 , 250)  cual sera el error

Comment: Comprendo, prueba: `getContentPane().getWidth()` lo que antes obtenías era el ancho del `JMenu`

Comment: Disculpa las molestias pero nuevamente no me funciona me marca error diciéndome que getContentPane()  no se a encontrado